# Autodesk viewer model security

Tags: security, autodesk-viewer

Simply wonder about the security of the model once it is loaded in the viewer. Is it possible to scrape/datamine/download or otherwise take this model out of the browser and into my local file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web is an open platform, so once the model is loaded in the viewer, there's no way of preventing the user from scraping its data.

On the other hand, it's also worth saying that the data that's being loaded into the viewer is **not** your original design file, but rather a special file format optimized for viewing on the web (think a PDF version of a Word document). As an example, if somebody were to mine the data of your Inventor assembly loaded in the viewer, they will be able to access the three.js meshes and some of the metadata attached to them, not the original components, solid bodies, etc.